# Weird python sys.path module resolution behavior

Tags: python, sys.path

I produced a minimal example of behavior that I thought was weird.

```
├── a
│   └── com
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── x
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test1.py
└── b
    └── com
        ├── __init__.py
        └── x
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test2.py
```

In the prior filestructure I set my working directory to the one that contains 'a' and 'b'. Then I run

```
# Works
python3 -c "import sys; sys.path = ['a', 'b']; import com.x.test1"
```

```
# Error
python3 -c "import sys; sys.path = ['a', 'b']; import com.x.test2"
```

For the second example, it seems that the first sys path entry matches the common prefix, but when it ultimately can't find module `test2` it errors out. I would have expected python to resolve it by matching the module prefix in the next sys path entry and finding the module in the b folder. Why doesn't it work like this? Seems like this makes it really hard for multiple packages in an organization with the same namespace to collaborate.

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in [the kind of package that *does* work like that](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/), but for most use cases, the behavior you're looking for isn't actually helpful.

Comment: That Java-style way of naming packages isn't common in Python. Normally the top-level directory of the package (`com` in your example) would be something meaningful ("tensorflow", "numpy" etc) and you wouldn't expect it to clash between two dependencies in the same project.